# NSOperation crash on isCancelled

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have implemented a concurrent nsoperation and have ARC enabled. Now my customer is experiencing a crash which I cannot reproduce. He sent me the follow crash log :

```
Date/Time:       2013-04-24 12:23:34.925 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.3 (12D78)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          30946 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           1
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  33196 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      FB8460EE-5199-C6FB-55DC-F927D7F81A80

Crashed Thread:  15  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: isCancelled


Thread 15 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff877f1250 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Myapp   0x000000010a608807 0x10a601000 + 30727
2   Myapp   0x000000010a650575 0x10a601000 + 324981
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8b66212f -[NSBlockOperation main] + 124
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8b638036 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 684
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8b63f861 __block_global_6 + 129
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff832d0f01 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff832cd0b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff832ce1fa _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 304
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff87d19d0b _pthread_wqthread + 404
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff87d041d1 start_wqthread + 13
```

My code looks like this:

```
-(void)start
{        
    // Always check for cancellation before launching the task.
    if ([self isCancelled])
    {
        // Must move the operation to the finished state if it is canceled.
        [self onCancelSyncOperation];
        return;
    }

    // If the operation is not canceled, begin executing the task.
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(main) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    executing = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
}

- (void)onCancelSyncOperation
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    executing = NO;
    finished = YES;

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}
```

It seems like the nsoperation is already released? when it tries to check for isCancelled?

Is this possible?

Comment: Just asking, `self` is a subclass of `NSOperation`?

Comment: Yup the class is a subsclass of NSOperation

Comment: Have you been able to symbolicate `1   Myapp   0x000000010a608807 0x10a601000 + 30727
2   Myapp   0x000000010a650575 0x10a601000 + 324981` ? This could provide some good insight.

Comment: I never did that. I'm pretty new to osx. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone can tell you why your app crashes by looking at this log. I haven't looked at your code, but you cut your crash-log, so it only shows system modules (lib.dispatch..., com.apple...). Typically the error is in the first occurrence of "com.myname...".

If this kind of crash `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)` appears along with an `objc_msgSend()`, it **probably** means you're trying to message to an object (or in other words: call a method of an object) that isn't there anymore. If you call that object, chances are very good that you'll find it, if you call it delayed or on another Thread or from a block, it will be a bit more complicated.

Your best chance to find the cause of this is to inspect your app with Instrument, using the Allocations or Leaks tool with NSZombies enabled (which is the default). You can launch Instruments from within Xcode. Then try to reproduce your crash. If you succeed, you might be able to find the class and location where the crash occurs.

If you don't know what to do with this answer, then check out the WWDC Developer Videos from Apple, there are some that show how to profile your app with Instruments (you'll need a [free] Dev Account to access the videos).

Good luck!

Comment: and, btw: is there some specific need to use an NSThread that gives you advantages over using an asynchronous block (with dispatch_async)?

Comment: The code is based off Apple concurrency programming guide. Thx for your reply. It's just difficult to reproduce the crash in order to profile it.

Comment: How old is the concurrency programming guide? If it's from before 2012, please check the online version. There's also a guide how to migrate from NSThreads towards async dispatching. This is so much easier than dealing with NSThreads and operations :-) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: It's from the online source. same link as you posted